# linear algebra: image, kernel and transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

> Given that $A$ is a $(n\times n)$ skew-symmetric matrix $(A^t = -A)$
>   and that $\mathrm{Img}(A) = \ker(A)$.
>
> Note here $n$ must be even from the rank nullity theorem, $\mathrm{rank}(A) =
>  \dim (\ker A )= n/2$.
>
> I need to show that there exists a $n/2$-dim subspace $V\subset
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the bilinear form $\langle v, Aw\rangle$ is
>   non-degenerate.

My question is that even on $\mathbb{R}^n$, since we know 
$$\mathrm{Img}(A) = \ker(A^T)^\perp =\ker(- A)^\perp = \ker(A)^\perp $$
together with the given condition $\mathrm{Img}(A) = \ker(A)$, we would have $\ker(A)^\perp =  \ker(A)$ but this is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I would try to ask for clarification on this problem if it is for a class since there seems to be something rotten in the state of Denmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there is no nonzero skew-symmetric matrix $A$ such that ${\rm Im} A\subset {\rm ker} A$. Because this last condition is equivalent to $A^2=0$, and since $A$ is skew-symmetric this implies that $A^TA=0$ and consequently $\Vert Ax\Vert=0$ for every vector $x$, i.e $A=0$.